# Как определить, откуда загружается картинка в браузере

Tags: javascript, кэширование

Как определить через js источник загрузки картинки в браузере, из кеша или же происходит запрос на сервер?

Способ "на глаз", то есть приглянуться к скорости появления картинки - не выход.
Ловить запрос со стороны сервера тоже не получится, только js.

Comment: Вопрос несколько странный. С одной стороны, вы спрашиваете, как программным путем узнать где картинка (и это скорее всего невозможно). С другой упомянули вариант "на глаз", что предполагает вообще не программную реализацию. Если вы просто хотите узнать откуда картинка, откройте инструменты разработчика по ф12, вкладку Сеть, и посмотрите все запросы для страницы, там будет и запрос картинки, и место откуда она берется.
Если вы это в коде хотите использовать и узнавать программным путем, то мне интересно, зачем такое вообще может потребоваться.

Comment: @teran, да, во вкладке `Networks`, во вкладке `size` пишется `(from memory cache)`, что вполне устроит за ответ. Я просто совсем забыл, что там это тоже можно посмотреть, обычно я там анимацию дебажу. Программный путь не обязателен был, а цель обычная - отладка.  Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Во вкладке `Networks`, во вкладке `size` пишется (`from memory cache`)

Comment: да ладно, шуток не понимаете?(

Comment: Неа не понимаю. Вы тупо сперли ответ топикстартера из коммента не постаравшись его даже уточнить или хотя бы провалидировать. Так что я считаю что он не несет пользы.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму тут лишь 2 комментария, в одном из которых явно сказано, что устроит за ответ. 
Понимаю, будь здесь огромное количество комментариев, среди которых ответ бы пришлось валидировать или цитировать.
Это была шутейка, не более - в том, что спер ответ, чуть проще будьте.

Comment: Это просто ок как комментарй для чувака который сам разобрался но не на мой взгляд совсем не ок как ответ, потому что в таком виде он в одной строчке содержит минимум две неточности не говоря уже о том что есть как минимум две настройки при которых это не сработает и это только для вебкита. Не поленились хотя бы скриншот сделать чтоли, я бы не возмущался. Но в таком виде это ответ отвратительного качества.

Comment: Ну окей, это шутка. Я сам любитель пошутить на СО. Но а в чем шутка-то?